# Pageable support for Spring Data JPA having jndi look up for entityManagerFactory

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I was following http://terasolunaorg.github.io/guideline/1.0.x/en/ArchitectureInDetail/Pagination.html  to implement Pagination support for my MVC application

When I try to start the JBoss Server,

```
nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.repo.MyRepository.searchEntitySC(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! 

Reason: Your persistence provider does not support extracting the JPQL query from a named query thus you can't use Pageable inside your query method. Make sure you have a JpaDialect configured at your EntityManagerFactoryBean as this affects discovering the concrete persistence provider.
```

I tried to follow, http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/99613-you-cannot-use-pageable-as-method-parameter-if-your-persistence-provider-cannot-extra

But I don't know how to apply the suggested configuration for entityManagerFactory

as my jpa-config.xml contains

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/pu/pc" />
```

Any other better suggestion is more than welcome!

**Environment**:

1. JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.2.0.GA
2. spring-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar
3. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar

standalone.xml contains:

```
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pc" pool-name="pcdatapool" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mysid</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>XXX</user-name>
                    <password>xxx</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="pcem">
       <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/pc</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>xxx.YYYYY</class>
     ...
    <class>yyyy.AAAAAAAAAA</class>      
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <!-- Use log category 'org.hibernate.SQL' to level 'debug' to output SQL from hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property  name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <!-- Use generate statistics this will help query performance tunning  -->
        <property  name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standalone.xml file remove the prefix *java:*. Then in persistence config file reference the jndi name you have in your standalone.xml but with the prefix. So:

persistence.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDatasource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pc" />
<mapping-file>META-INF/announcement-queries.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
```

jboss.datasource.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="jboss/datasources/pc" pool-name="pcdatapool" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
...
</datasource>
```

applicationContext.xml (Spring)

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDatasource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mypacjage" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How to configure JpaDialect?

Comment: Thanks for your update. Added my persistence.xml in the question. If I've understood your answer, I think <class> in persistence.xml  can be do away with using <property name="packagesToScan"...  in applicationContext.xml. Similarly for hibernate properties.    But how map the rest like   <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>

Comment: The mapping-file could go into the persistence.xml... added in the example

Comment: Anyway, your persistence.xml is right. You can scan your entities classes using: <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
within your persistence.xml file.